# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' when calling .iloc()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

I'm currently doing some AI research for a project and for that I have to get used to a framework called "Pytorch". That's fine and all but following the official tutorial (found [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/data_loading_tutorial.html)) the code doesn't run properly.

The idea is that I analyse a set of facial features from a prepared dataset and then do something with it (haven't gotten to that part yet). But when I run this piece of code:

```
img_name = os.path.join(self.root_dir, self.landmarks_frame.iloc([index, 0]))  # At this point 'index' is 0
```

The dataset is initialized like this:

```
face_dataset = fDataset(csv_file='faces/face_landmarks.csv', root_dir='faces/')
```

And here is where the error pops up:

```
for i in range(len(face_dataset)):
    sample = face_dataset[i]  # <-- right there
```

That leads to the getter function:

```
def __getitem__(self, index):
    img_name = os.path.join(self.root_dir, self.landmarks_frame.iloc([index, 0]))
    image = io.imread(img_name)
    landmarks = self.landmarks_frame.iloc[index, 1:].as_matrix()
    landmarks = landmarks.astype('float').reshape(-1, 2)
    sample = {'image': image, 'landmarks': landmarks}
```

Found in my `FaceLandmarksDataset(Dataset):` class I simply get the error of the title. This is strange I find, because I can read the dataset just fine as a frame in PyCharm:
[image: Dataset Inspector]

Where the first picture is clearly visible. I have checked as well that it is in the folder that I'm looking in.

Can anyone help out? :)

Comment: You haven't read the tutorial correctly. It does not say to *call* `iloc`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Mikhail pointed out the mistake. Just me being a derp.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need the parentheses with `iloc`:

```
self.landmarks_frame.iloc[index, 0]
```